# Firebase Function returning connection error

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase functions Database Triggers.

My Function :

```
exports.function_name = functions.database
  .ref("/transact/{entry_type}/{id1}/{id2}/trigger_cross_entry_function")
  .onCreate((data, context) => {
    console.log("trigger_cross_entry_function value", data.val());

    if (data.val() == true) {

      console.log("Function Calling parent data");

      return data.ref.parent.once('value').then(function(snapshot){


      }, function(error) {
        // The Promise was rejected.
        console.error("THIS IS THE ERROR:"+error);
      });

    } else {
      console.log("Function Returned");
      return 0;
    }
 });
```

Whenever I want to trigger this function I put trigger_cross_entry_function into that partcular path from the Mobile App. Everything works fine and function is called as expected.

After sometime If I again try to do the same thing it gives me

`Function execution took 16 ms, finished with status: 'connection error'`

If I restart the function than it again works perfectly.
and If I trigger it continously than it has no issue.

But once I keep it idle and try to trigger it
again after sometime, it gives me this error.

And I am using Firebase Pay as you go Plan.

Also, as you can see I am returning all the promises correctly and function is being triggered everytime but It doesnt go into the function. it just exit with connection error.

What might be the cause for this ? I have a spent a day finding this.

Comment: we're seeing the exact same issue, and a few others on firebase slack are too. I've been in contact with support, and they say their engineers are on it.

Comment: Yeah, also experiencing this intermittently starting today.

Comment: Thank you. Even I contacted them so they replied the same

Answer (score 1):

Experiencing the same issue. Looks like Google changed the status of the service to down
https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/18046
https://status.firebase.google.com/

So most likely the Google side problem.